# Removed a page from a Wordpress live website, but it still showing up in google search

Tags: wordpress

Working on a live Wordpress website deleted a page that has been published by mistake:

1- Turned the page into a Draft page, but it was still showing

2- Moved the page to Trash on the Wordpress dashboard and then deleted it permanently from the bin, but it still showing in the google search.

3-Cleared the catch, but it still showing up in google search and the link returns a 404 error.

---

Following up Google instruction:

> Make removal permanent:
>
> - Remove or update the actual content from your site (images, pages,
>     directories) and make sure that your web server returns either a 404
>     (Not Found) or 410 (Gone) HTTP status code. Non-HTML files (like PDFs)
>     should be completely removed from your server. (Learn more about HTTP
>     status codes)
> - Block access to the content, for example by requiring a password.
> - Indicate that the page should not to be indexed using the noindex meta
>     tag. This is less secure than the other methods.The Remove URLs tool is 
>     only a temporary

**The first part is easy and shows the 404 error.**
The second part:
[image]

**Turning the page to a password protected page, now it takes me to password protected page and it is still showing on the Google search.**

Also for noindex I had the following options:
[image]

Any idea why or any recommendation?

Thank you

Comment: Google isn't instant.

Comment: @ProEvilz any idea how long? I'm receiving complains. Thank you.

Comment: Please see & follow my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google search is based on **indexing**, it takes time to update your website's content, pages, and dependencies. Search updates are based on mechanism of Google crawlers (so called spiders). These spiders crawls your website's content and follow your meta tags and robots.txt file.

Generally, it will take about 1-3 days to get your page removed from the search results. There are no quick ways to do it as it is based on indexing. Make sure you update your Google webmasters account (just check for errors on your account which relates to a page not found).